# LeveyPopListView multiple calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using [LeveyPopListView](https://github.com/levey/LeveyPopListView) i changed the size of LeveyPopListView to prevent multiple calls of LeveyPopListView. But in my app when I tap too fast its displays another LeveyPopListView overlapping the first LeveyPopListView. See image for reference (the LeveyPopListView has a darker background because there two overlapping pop up).

[image]

(main page the one that calls LeveyPopListView)
created a method for creating LeveyPopListView

```
- (void) createLeveyPopList
{
NSInteger numberOfJobs = [[[[[self.FilterDictionary objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] valueForKey:@"company_group"] valueForKey:@"job_count"] objectAtIndex:[self.jobsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] intValue];
NSString *jobs_name = xapp.jobName;
NSString *company_name;

if(numberOfJobs > 1)
{
    isToDetail = false;
    NSString *company_id = [[[[self.FilterDictionary objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] valueForKey:@"company_group"] valueForKey:@"company_id"] objectAtIndex:[self.jobsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
    company_name = [[[[self.FilterDictionary objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] valueForKey:@"company_group"] valueForKey:@"company_name"] objectAtIndex:[self.jobsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
    NSDictionary *specificCompany = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:company_id,@"company_id", nil];

    if(specificCompany.count>0)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:specificCompany
                                                           options:0 // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                             error:&error];

        if (! jsonData)
        {
            NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
        }
        else
        {
            strJsonStringFilter = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        }
    }

    allJobsDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[network getData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"get_all_job_offers?pt_id=%@&filter=%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"pt_id"], strJsonStringFilter]] options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    jobsToDisplay=(NSArray*)[allJobsDictionary objectForKey:@"sub_slots"];
}

if(self.lplv != nil)
    return;

self.lplv = [[LeveyPopListView alloc] initWithTitle:company_name options:jobsToDisplay jobName:jobs_name handler:^(NSInteger anIndex){
}];

self.lplv.delegate = self;
[self.lplv showInView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

(located in LeveyPopListView class)
code for my close button:

```
_close = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [_close addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(fadeOut)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

(located in LeveyPopListView class)
FADEOUT method:

```
- (void)fadeOut {
[UIView animateWithDuration:.35 animations:^{
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
    self.alpha = 0.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"FINISH");
    if (finished) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
        self.lplv.delegate = nil;
        [self.lplv removeFromSuperview];
        self.lplv = nil;
    }
}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, the method on which you create the `LeveyPopListView` triggers more than once when you tap fast to create the list, resulting in creation of more lists than the required.

I think you should insert a check in the list creation method which confirms that 'if the list is already been created than does not create the new one else create one'.

You can do so by declaring the instance of `LeveyPopListView` as member variable as -

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) LeveyPopListView *m_lplv;
```

inside create list

```
- (void) createLeveyPopList
{
    if(self.m_lplv != nil)
        return;

    self.m_lplv = [[LeveyPopListView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share Photo  to..." options:_options];
    self.m_lplv.delegate = self;
    [self.m_lplv showInView:self.window animated:YES];
    [self.m_lplv release];
}
```

Also create a remove method to remove the list from super view as -

```
- (void) removeLeveyPopList
{
    self.m_lplv.delegate = nil;
    [self.m_lplv removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Call the above method `removeLeveyPopList` when you are done with the list, which will remove the list from the superview.

And again when you need to create the list call `createLeveyPopList` which will check if the list is already created, if YES than it won't create the new else create one.

Comment: here's what i did, i called the createLeveyPopList in the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier. Now when I tap the close button and call crateLeveyPopList the LeveyPopList is not created. This is because the code m.lplv is not empty. Where should I call the removeLeveyPopList? Please see my update for the close button method.

Comment: Change the [self removeFromSuperview]; to [self.lplv removeFromSuperview]; in method - (void)fadeOut {
[UIView animateWithDuration:.35 animations:^{
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
    self.alpha = 0.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"FINISH");
    if (finished) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
        [self.lplv removeFromSuperview];
    }
}];
}

Comment: hmm..the fadeOut Method is called and created in the leveyPopListView class..i changed [self removeFromSuperview]; to [self.lplv removeFromSuperview]; still got the same result..

Comment: in completion  block set self.lplv.delegate = nil; [self.lplv removeFromSuperview]; and assign self.lplv = nil; then try.

Comment: i tried it and when i log heres the result that i am getting: LPLV: <LeveyPopListView: 0x14d525a10; frame = (-48 -85.2; 416 738.4); transform = [1.3, 0, 0, 1.3, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; layer = <CALayer: 0x170a27880>>
it's still getting a frame size?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74556/discussion-between-aianlee-and-sanjay-mohnani).

Comment: have you implemented - (void)leveyPopListViewDidCancel delegate method?

Comment: in the class where you have created the self.lplv instance implement - (void)leveyPopListViewDidCancel as - (void)leveyPopListViewDidCancel{self.lplv = nil;}

Comment: have you implemented the - (void)leveyPopListViewDidCancel delegate of leveyPopListView?

Comment: where should i call leveyPopListViewDidCancel..currently in my code it is called in my touchesEnded event..

Comment: implement the delegate methods -

Comment: #pragma mark - LeveyPopListView delegates
- (void)leveyPopListView:(LeveyPopListView *)popListView didSelectedIndex:(NSInteger)anIndex;
- (void)leveyPopListViewDidCancel;

Comment: in the class in which you created leveyPopListView instance

Answer (score 0):

I have added another answer following the edits of your question and discussion done on the previous answer -

Suppose you have a class called `CustomViewController`

Inside `CustomViewController.h`

Create property for the instance of `LeveyPopListView` as

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) LeveyPopListView *m_lplv;
```

Inside `CustomViewController.m`

create your list as -

```
- (void) createLeveyPopList
{
NSInteger numberOfJobs = [[[[[self.FilterDictionary objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] valueForKey:@"company_group"] valueForKey:@"job_count"] objectAtIndex:[self.jobsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] intValue];
NSString *jobs_name = xapp.jobName;
NSString *company_name;

if(numberOfJobs > 1)
{
    isToDetail = false;
    NSString *company_id = [[[[self.FilterDictionary objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] valueForKey:@"company_group"] valueForKey:@"company_id"] objectAtIndex:[self.jobsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
    company_name = [[[[self.FilterDictionary objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] valueForKey:@"company_group"] valueForKey:@"company_name"] objectAtIndex:[self.jobsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
    NSDictionary *specificCompany = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:company_id,@"company_id", nil];

    if(specificCompany.count>0)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:specificCompany
                                                           options:0 // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                             error:&error];

        if (! jsonData)
        {
            NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
        }
        else
        {
            strJsonStringFilter = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        }
    }

    allJobsDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[network getData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"get_all_job_offers?pt_id=%@&filter=%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"pt_id"], strJsonStringFilter]] options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    jobsToDisplay=(NSArray*)[allJobsDictionary objectForKey:@"sub_slots"];
}

if(self.m_lplv != nil)
    return;

self.m_lplv = [[LeveyPopListView alloc] initWithTitle:company_name options:jobsToDisplay jobName:jobs_name handler:^(NSInteger anIndex){
}];

self.m_lplv.delegate = self;
[self.m_lplv showInView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

also implement the `LeveyPopListView` delegates in the same class(`CustomViewController.m`) as-

```
#pragma mark - LeveyPopListView delegates
 - (void)leveyPopListView:(LeveyPopListView *)popListView didSelectedIndex:(NSInteger)anIndex
{
    // selected an item from popListView at anIndex
    // code to be executed on selecting any item from the list
}
 - (void)leveyPopListViewDidCancel
{
   // called when the cross button of the list is tapped
   self.m_lplv = nil
}
```

**Note**:

1) Following above implementation details, you can resolve the issue of multiple list creation when clicking fast and also in `leveyPopListViewDidCancel` delegate you will set the list instance to nil as `self.m_lplv = nil;` and this will help in creating the list again.

2) Remember you need not to do any coding in any method of the `LeveyPopListView.h` or `LeveyPopListView.m` to achieve your requirements. Unless and Until you need to change the current implementation of the list creation.